# How to get selenium to wait for ajax response?

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, selenium

How can I get selenium to wait for something like a calendar widget to load? Right now I am just doing a `Thread.sleep(2500)` after exporting the testcase to a junit program.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would use

```
waitForElementPresent(locator)
```

This will wait until the element is present in the DOM.

If you need to check the element is visible, you may be better using

```
waitForElementHeight(locator)
```

Comment: What if ajax does redirect and selenium doesn't know about it? How to work with that?

Answer (score 28):

A more general solution than waiting for an element would be to wait for all the connections to the server to close. This will allow you to wait for all ajax calls to finish, even if they don't have any callback and thus don't affect the page. More details can be found [here](http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/?p=111).

Using C# and jQuery, I have created the following method to wait for all AJax calls to complete (if anyone have more direct ways of accessing JS variables from C#, please comment):

```
internal void WaitForAjax(int timeOut = 15)
{
    var value = "";
    RepeatUntil(
        () => value = GetJavascriptValue("jQuery.active"), 
        () => value == "0", 
        "Ajax calls did not complete before timeout"
    );
}

internal void RepeatUntil(Action repeat, Func<bool> until, string errorMessage, int timeout = 15)
{
    var end = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    var complete = false;

    while (DateTime.Now < end)
    {
        repeat();
        try
        {
            if (until())
            {
                complete = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (!complete)
        throw new TimeoutException(errorMessage);
}

internal string GetJavascriptValue(string variableName)
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _selenium.RunScript(String.Format(@"window.$('body').append(""<input type='text' value='""+{0}+""' id='{1}'/>"");", variableName, id));
    return _selenium.GetValue(id);
}
```

Comment: this.selenium.GetEval("(window.jQuery || { active : 0 }).active ") is a little more direct than the input box.  It also doesn't error if jQuery is not on the page.

Comment: What is the type of the variable __selenium? I am not able to fin it in the object model

Comment: Mauricio, it's been quite a while since I worked with Selenium so I can't recall the details, but my guess would be the IWebDriver instance.

Comment: @AskarKalykov exactly.

Comment: nice, trying to figure out the same thing but for PHP here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590437/php-webdriver-wait-for-ajax-to-finish-executing

Answer (score 16):

If using python, you may use this function, which clicks the button and waits for the DOM change:

```
def click_n_wait(driver, button, timeout=5):
    source = driver.page_source
    button.click()
    def compare_source(driver):
        try:
            return source != driver.page_source
        except WebDriverException:
            pass
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(compare_source)
```

(CREDIT: based on [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089040/977116))

Comment: Unfortunately some pages have loading animations which ruin this trick because page_source is updated but you don't have the data yet.

Comment: It worked for me, I have a page with multiple XHR  requests at on single button click, so just waiting for `jQuery.active == 0` does not work.

Comment: Thanks @nimo, this works well. I had a loading animation on my page so I modified the lines `driver.page_source` to `driver.find_element_by_xpath(comparator_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')`. This way it didn't matter what was going on when the loading element was in animation.

Comment: Thanks  @eNc ,This works well but need some fix. In my web page, there is a default AJAX request , so I must wait it  completed before click the button. otherwise，the source change caused not by the click I want.   I wait the “source” not empty（This depends on the initial state of the element）before I click the button.

Answer (score 4):

With webdriver aka selenium2 you can use implicit wait configuration as mentionned on
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait

Using Java:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Or using python:

```python
from selenium import webdriver

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = ff.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

Answer (score 4):

This work for me

```
public  void waitForAjax(WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote next method as my solution (I hadn't any load indicator):

```
public static void waitForAjax(WebDriver driver, String action) {
       driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
               "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                       "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                       "xhr.open('POST', '/" + action + "', true);" +
                       "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
                       "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
                       "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
                       "  }" +
                       "};" +
                       "xhr.send();");
}
```

Then I jsut called this method with actual driver.
More description in this [post](http://hrabosch.com/2016/05/12/35/).

Comment: downvote. answers are supposed to contain actual answers... they are not for driving traffic to your personal blog.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I dont care about traffic, but Ok, I'll insert code from post here. This post is only another option, because other answers wont worked for me.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I hope that now it is OK for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

The code (C#) bellow ensures that the target element is displayed:

```
        internal static bool ElementIsDisplayed()
        {
          IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.Url = "http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp";
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
          By locator = By.CssSelector("input[value='csharp']:first-child");
          IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
          {
            return d.FindElement(locator);
          });
          return myDynamicElement.Displayed;
        }
```

If the page supports jQuery it can be used the [jQuery.active function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function) to ensure that the target element is retrieved after all the ajax calls are finished:

```
 public static bool ElementIsDisplayed()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        By locator = By.CssSelector("input[value='csharp']:first-child");
        return wait.Until(d => ElementIsDisplayed(d, locator));
    }

    public static bool ElementIsDisplayed(IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        try
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(by).Displayed)
            {
                //jQuery is supported.
                if ((bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return window.$ != undefined"))
                {
                    return (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $.active == 0");
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm for me :

```
public void waitForAjax() {

    try {
        WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation;   
        expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driverjs) {

                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driverjs;
                return js.executeScript("return((window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0))").equals("true");
            }
        };
        driverWait.until(expectation);
    }       
    catch (TimeoutException exTimeout) {

       // fail code
    }
    catch (WebDriverException exWebDriverException) {

       // fail code
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, i wanted to wait for ajax requests so that the loading panel would have disappeared, I have inspected the html before and after the requests, found that there is a div for the ajax loading panel, the dix is displayed during the ajax request, and hidden after the request ends. I have created a function to wait for the panel to be displayed, then wait for it to be hidden

`public void WaitForModalPanel()
{
    string element_xpath = ".//*[@id='ajaxLoadingModalPanelContainer'  and not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]";
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(element_xpath)));
    element_xpath = ".//*[@id='ajaxLoadingModalPanelContainer' and contains(@style,'DISPLAY: none')]";
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(element_xpath)));
}`

Check [this](http://amir-shenodua.blogspot.com/2013/06/selenium-dealing-with-html-loading.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you can wait for active connections to get closed:

```
private static void WaitForReady() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, waitForElement);
    wait.Until(driver => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
}
```

My observation is this is not reliable as data transfer happens very quickly. Much more time is consumed on data processing and rendering on the page and even `jQuery.active == 0` data might not be yet on the page.

Much wiser is to use an [explicit wait](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/) for element to be shown on the page, see some of the answers related to this.

The best situation is if your web application have some custom loader or indication that data is being processed. In this case you can just wait for this indication to hide.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a groovy version based on Morten Christiansen's answer.

```
void waitForAjaxCallsToComplete() {
    repeatUntil(
            { return getJavaScriptFunction(driver, "return (window.jQuery || {active : false}).active") },
            "Ajax calls did not complete before timeout."
    )
}

static void repeatUntil(Closure runUntilTrue, String errorMessage, int pollFrequencyMS = 250, int timeOutSeconds = 10) {
    def today = new Date()
    def end = today.time + timeOutSeconds
    def complete = false;

    while (today.time < end) {
        if (runUntilTrue()) {
            complete = true;
            break;
        }

        sleep(pollFrequencyMS);
    }
    if (!complete)
        throw new TimeoutException(errorMessage);
}

static String getJavaScriptFunction(WebDriver driver, String jsFunction) {
    def jsDriver = driver as JavascriptExecutor
    jsDriver.executeScript(jsFunction)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the control you are waiting for is an "Ajax" web element, the following code will wait for it, or any other Ajax web element to finish loading or performing whatever it needs to do so that you can more-safely continue with your steps.

```
    public static void waitForAjaxToFinish() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() { 
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) { 
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return jQuery.active == 0").equals(true);
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Please try to add some explanation over your code on how you think this code solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue seemed due to ajax delays but was related to internal iframes inside the main page.
In seleminum it is possible to switch to internal frames with:

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("body");
    driver.switchTo().frame("bodytab");
```

I use java. After that I was able to locate the element

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("e_46")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below can be used for cases where jQuery is not available.

By actively monitoring the logs, we can ensure that all files and responses have been completed with certainty.

I have tested this solution for Chrome, but you should also ensure it is supported in other browsers. For example, Safari does not support this method.

Also, don't forget to set the capability for these logs to be visible.

```
 LoggingPreferences preferences = new LoggingPreferences();
    preferences.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", preferences);
```

You should use with WebDriverWait instance. After that, just call the waitUntilPageIsReady() method.

```
public class IsPageReady implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean> {
private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(IsPageReady.class);

@NullableDecl
@Override
public Boolean apply(@NullableDecl WebDriver webDriver) {
    try {
        if (webDriver == null)
            return false;
        LogEntries logs = WebDriverManager.getInstance().getWebDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
        return ready = logs.getAll().isEmpty();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("There was a problem checking if the page was ready!");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

just call:

```
public void waitUntilPageIsReady() {
    getWebDriverWait().until(new IsPageReady());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to capture this by writing a custom HTTP listener in JavaScript as follows. For those who wish to examine this script, you can check out this link: https://gist.github.com/erdemkiiliic/3e3caa666ca1c950c4db3e94a8d3f049

```
public static void waitForAjaxToFinish() {
  String customScriptForHTTPListener = "if(void 0===window.jsXMLHTTPListener){let i={isCallFinishedStatus:1,pointerSize:0,pointerFinishSize:0,isCallFinished:function(){return 1===this.isCallFinishedStatus},setCallFinished:function(i=0){this.isCallFinishedStatus=i},bindEvents:function(i,e){var t=e.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;e.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send=function(){i.setCallFinished(0);var s=this;i.pointerSize++;var n=e.setInterval(function(){4==s.readyState&&(i.pointerFinishSize++,i.pointerSize===i.pointerFinishSize?i.setCallFinished(1):i.setCallFinished(0),clearInterval(n))},1);return t.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments))}},init:function(){this.bindEvents(this,window)}};window.jsXMLHTTPListener=i,window.jsXMLHTTPListener.init();let e=window.jsXMLHTTPListener.isCallFinished();console.log(e);return e;}else{let t=window.jsXMLHTTPListener.isCallFinished();console.log(t);return t;}";

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition < Boolean > () {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
      return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
          "return document.readyState").equals("complete") &&
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
          customScriptForHTTPListener).equals(true);
    }
  });
}
```

This script returns either true or false. If there is no active XHR request at that moment, it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.get_log('performance'), you can get message about  'Network.requestWillBeSent', 'Network.responseReceived', 'Network.loadingFinished'.

and all of them has a 'requestId' that stand for a request.

If you have the URL of the ajax , you can get requestId from 'Network.requestWillBeSent' or 'Network.responseReceived', and wait the requestId appear in the 'Network.loadingFinished' message.

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {"performance": "ALL"})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

def wait_ajax_finish(driver, url, start_time=0, timeout=50):
    request_id = ''

    def check_finish(driver):
        nonlocal request_id
        for log in driver.get_log('performance'):
            if start_time * 1000 > log['timestamp'] or 'message' not in log:
                continue
            log_entry = json.loads(log['message'])
            try:
                method = log_entry['message']['method']
                params = log_entry['message']['params']
                # get requestId 
                if not request_id and \
                        method in ['Network.requestWillBeSent', 'Network.responseReceived'] and \
                        params['request']['method'] in ['POST', 'GET']:
                    if method == 'Network.requestWillBeSent' and  url in params['request']['url']:
                        requestId = params['requestId']
                    if method == 'Network.responseReceived' and url in params['response']['url']:
                        requestId = params['requestId']
                # check requestId 
                if request_id and method in ['Network.loadingFinished'] and request_id == params['requestId']:
                    request_id = ''
                    return params['requestId']
            except Exception as e:
                pass
    
    return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(check_finish)

# the url may accessed by default
driver.get('https://xxx.yyy.com/home')

button = driver.find_element(......)
start_time = time.time() # We should use logs after this time
button.click()

request_id = wait_ajax_finish(driver, 'https://xxx.yyy.com/get/xxxx', start_time, 120)
time.sleep(1)
# I advise sleep 1 or more seconds  before do other things.
# because the data need some time to render to the web page by js.

# you can get the result by the request_id
print(driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.getResponseBody", {"requestId": request_id}))
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is my code for fetch. Took me while researching because jQuery.active doesn't work with fetch. Here is the answer helped me proxy fetch, but its only for ajax not fetch [mock for selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575572/monkey-patch-xmlhttprequest-onreadystatechange)

```
public static void customPatchXMLHttpRequest(WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return window.openHTTPs");
            if (numberOfAjaxConnections instanceof Long) {
                return;
            }
            String script = "  (function() {" + "var oldFetch = fetch;"
                    + "window.openHTTPs = 0; console.log('starting xhttps');" + "fetch = function(input,init ){ "
                    + "window.openHTTPs++; "

                    + "return oldFetch(input,init).then( function (response) {"
                    + "      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {"
                    + "          window.openHTTPs--;  console.log('Call completed. Remaining active calls: '+ window.openHTTPs); return response;"
                    + "      } else {"
                    + "          window.openHTTPs--; console.log('Call fails. Remaining active calls: ' + window.openHTTPs);  return response;"
                    + "      };})" + "};" + "var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;"
                    + "XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {"
                    + "window.openHTTPs++; console.log('xml ajax called');"
                    + "this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {" + "if(this.readyState == 4) {"
                    + "window.openHTTPs--; console.log('xml ajax complete');" + "}" + "}, false);"
                    + "oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);" + "}" +

                    "})();";
            jsDriver.executeScript(script);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Web driver: " + driver + " cannot execute javascript");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For those who is using primefaces, just do:

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active==0", defaultWaitingPeriod);
```

Comment: waitForCondition

void waitForCondition(java.lang.String script,
                      java.lang.String timeout)
Runs the specified JavaScript snippet repeatedly until it evaluates to "true". The snippet may have multiple lines, but only the result of the last line will be considered.
Note that, by default, the snippet will be run in the runner's test window, not in the window of your application. To get the window of your application, you can use the JavaScript snippet selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow(), and then run your JavaScript in there

Comment: it is only for Selenium RC. Selenium WebDriver doesnot support feature

Comment: Is WebDriver the same as IDE ?