# Monkey patch XMLHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, monkeypatching

How would go about monkey patching the `XMLHTTPRequest`'s `onreadystatechange` function. I'm trying to add a function that would be called when every ajax request made from a page come back.

I know this sounds like a terrible idea, but the use case is quite peculiar. I want to use a certain SDK with a console (jqconsole) but show status and results from ajax calls within the console without modifying the external SDK.

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event) which had great info, but nothing on monkey patching the callback which seem to exceed my JavaScript skills.

P.S Can't use jQuery since it only supports ajax calls made from jQuery not from `XMLHTTPRequests` directly which is the case here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To monkey-patch `XMLHttpRequest`s, you need to know how an AJAX request is generally constructed:

1. Constructor invocation
2. Preparation the request (`setRequestHeader()`, `open()`)
3. Sending the request (`.send`).

### General-purpose patch

```
(function(xhr) {
    function banana(xhrInstance) { // Example
        console.log('Monkey RS: ' + xhrInstance.readyState);
    }
    // Capture request before any network activity occurs:
    var send = xhr.send;
    xhr.send = function(data) {
        var rsc = this.onreadystatechange;
        if (rsc) {
            // "onreadystatechange" exists. Monkey-patch it
            this.onreadystatechange = function() {
                banana(this);
                return rsc.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
```

The previous assumed that `onreadystatechange` was assigned to the `onreadystatechange` handler. For simplicity, I didn't include the code for [other events](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handlers), such as `onload`. Also, I did not account for events added using `addEventListener`.

The previous patch runs for all requests. But what if you want to limit the patch to a specific request only? A request with a certain URL or async flag and a specific request body?

### Conditional monkey-patch

Example: Intercepting all `POST` requests whose request body contains "TEST"

```
(function(xhr) {
    function banana(xhrInstance) { // Example
        console.log('Monkey RS: ' + xhrInstance.readyState);
    }
    // 
    var open = xhr.open;
    xhr.open = function(method, url, async) {
        // Test if method is POST
        if (/^POST$/i.test(method)) {
            var send = this.send;
            this.send = function(data) {
                // Test if request body contains "TEST"
                if (typeof data === 'string' && data.indexOf('TEST') >= 0) {
                    var rsc = this.onreadystatechange;
                    if (rsc) {
                        // Apply monkey-patch
                        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            banana(this);
                            return rsc.apply(this, arguments);
                        };
                    }
                }
                return send.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }
        return open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
```

The main techniques used is the transparent rewrite using...

```
var original = xhr.method; 
xhr.method = function(){
    /*...*/;
    return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

My examples are very basic, and can be extended to meet your exact wishes. That's up to you, however.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can ignore IE...

```
//Totally untested code, typed at the SO <textarea>... but the concept *should* work, let me know if it doesn't.
var OldXMLRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

// Create a new instance
function XMLHttpRequest() {
  var ajax = new OldXMLRequest();

  // save old function
  var f = ajax.onreadystatechange;
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Whatever!");
    f(); // Call the old function
  }
  return ajax;
}
```

Comment: 1. When the `XHR` object is constructed, there's certainly no `readystatechange` event handler. 2. When calling the method using `f()`, the context is lost: `this` should be the xhr instance, not `window` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

you can learn from [Ajax-hook](https://github.com/wendux/Ajax-hook/) written by chinese!

it is a advanced js to enable Monkey patch XMLHTTPRequest