# Javascript HTTP data stream reset response

Tags: javascript, http

I've been having a hard time writing websockets in PHP, so I decided to try to download a datastream.
It works, I can get content in different times, parse it, and use it, but the entire response is saved into memory...

Is there a way to reset the request's response every time in `onreadystatechange` function? (where that comment is)

Removing the comment, I get this error:

> test.html:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'responseText' of object '#'

A working code for streaming:

```
class HTTPStream {
    constructor(url, callback, error) {
        this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var previous_text = '';

        if (typeof error === "function")
            this.request.onerror = error;

        this.request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (this.request.readyState > 2) {
                var new_response = this.request.responseText.substring(previous_text.length);
                if(new_response != "") {
                    var result = JSON.parse(new_response);
                    callback(result);
                }
                previous_text = this.request.responseText;
                //this.request.responseText = "";
            }
        };
        this.request.open("GET", url, true);
        this.request.send();
    }

    cancel() {
        this.request.abort();
    }
}

new HTTPStream('test.php', (m) => console.log(m));
```

Here is a log:
[image]

---

**EDIT:**

By suggestions, I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447335/how-can-i-modify-the-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-received-by-another-function), but unfortunately you can set it to writable only once, and that is it. I have lots of outputs, not just once.

Comment: If you want a simple one-way system from server to client, you may want to check out _Server Sent Events_.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Thank you! This is what I was trying to implement.

Comment: I can turn that into a full answer, if you'd like.