# Dynamically set getters and setters for a class

Tags: javascript

I can set a property of a class externally from a string value after it's been created like so

```js
class Class {
  //Nothing
}

let storageClass = new Class();

storageClass['value'] = 'Hello World';

document.write(storageClass.value);
```

But I need to track changes to all the attributes so I can use `get` and `set`, but then I can't add a new property based just on `storageClass['value'] = 'Hello World';`. For example, I'd have to add the get and set functions if I wanted to do `storageClass['valueNumberTwo'] = 'A Second Value';`

```js
class Class {
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  
  set value(value) {
    this._value = value;
    console.log('Value Changed');
  }
}

let storageClass = new Class();

storageClass['value'] = 'Hello World';

document.write(storageClass.value);
```

Is there a way to still do that if I know all the properties that could be created when I create the class?

Comment: Why do you say you can't use `storageClass['value'] = 'Hello World';` if you use getters and setters?

Comment: Don't I need to make a `set myCustomValue()` and `get myCustomValue()` for each one?

Comment: Yes, you will need to.

Comment: Is there a way to make a set and get for all properties?

Comment: Check my edited answer. My goal is to be able to use something like `storageClass['valueNumberTwo'] = 'A Second Value';` to add more set and get functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to handle dynamic get and set operations.

```js
class Class {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return target['_' + prop];
      },
      set(obj, prop, value) {
        obj['_' + prop] = value;
        console.log('value changed');
      }
    });
  }
}
let storageClass = new Class;
storageClass['value'] = 'Hello World';
document.write(storageClass.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway I could do this within the class instead of when I declare it?

Comment: @Jack You can return the `Proxy` from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `get/set` for all properties using the ES6 `Proxy` construct, which allows you to implement low-level methods for an object (like `get`, which is invoked when **any** property is accessed).

See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for details.

Note that as an ES6 feature this has broad, but not universal, browser support (does not work in Internet Explorer, for example), and cannot be polyfilled because the features it uses did not exist in older versions of JavaScript.