# Selenium Python- If cannot find element, close everything and restart

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, restart

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("user_first_name")
```

If python cant find the element in the page, what do I add to the code to close the browser/ program and restart everything?

Comment: Why do you need to restart the whole thing and check if element is there? Is it being showed randomly, or what is the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe The program runs on a loop an n number of times. When it couldn't locate an element, it raised an error and the whole loop stopped. I think reloading the page would work just fine.. rather than restarting the whole thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`WebdriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) and wait until the element can be found, or timeout occurred:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('user_first_name'))
    # do smth with the found element
except TimeoutException:
    print "Element Not Found"
    driver.close()
```

---

Another option would be to put the whole opening the browser, getting the page, finding element into a endless while loop from which you would `break` if element is found:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://example.com')

    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("user_first_name")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.close()
        continue
    else:
        break

# do smth with the element
```

Answer (score 0):

If your'e waiting for an Ajax call to be completed you could use `waitForElementPresent(locator)`. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835179/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-ajax-response) for more options for handling the wait.