# Selenium will not find my elements

Tags: python, selenium, element

[firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1rqj.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb2yt.png)

I have a project that I chose Selenium to open 1-5 links.  It's stopping at the 3rd link.  I've followed the same methods for the previously successful requests.  I've allowed 17 seconds and watched as I can see the page load, before the script continues to run in my console.  I'm just not sure why it can't find this link, and I hope it's something I'm simply overlooking...

```
from selenium import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import csv
import time

username = "xxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxx"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://tm.login.trendmicro.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php")
assert "Trend" in driver.title
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("input_username")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("input_password")
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_id("btn_logon")
elem1.send_keys(username)
elem2.send_keys(password)
elem3.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(7)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
elem4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.float-right.open-console")
elem4.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(17)
elem5 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a.btn_left")
elem5.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Post your code, not a picture of your code.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is rather unreliable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835179/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-ajax-response

Comment: Also include the actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one of the reasons is elem5 is looking for the element by tag name, but you are passing it a css tag.  "a.btn_left" is not an html tag name and so your script will never actually find it, because it simply doesn't exist in the dom.

You either need to find it by css_selector or better yet by Xpath.  If you want to make this as reliable possible and more future proof I always try and find elements on a page with at least 2 descriptors using Xpath if possible.

Change this:

```
elem5 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a.btn_left")
```

To this:

```
elem5 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn_left")
```

You will almost never use tag_name, mostly because it will always retrieve the first tag you pass to it, so "a" will always find the first link and click it, yours however does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up solving it with this code.  I increased time to 20 secs, believe it or not, I did try the find by css, I actually left the a.btn_left, and cycled through all the elements, and none of them worked, fortunately, I could access by tab and key functions so that worked for now.

```
time.sleep(20)
driver.get("https://wfbs-svc-nabu.trendmicro.com/wfbs-svc/portal/en/view/cm")
elem5 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Devices")
elem5.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```