# i am getting an exception on my dashboard page due to AJax huge calls how to tickle it in selenium web driver with java

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to automate a web base application but due to the huge Ajax calls i get an exception even the element still exist on web page my i think due to the Dom code is executed before page load completion even i am using different wait method but all in vain :

```
Exception in thread "main" Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 2530
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'lt07', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\NATASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1812_20595}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=64.0.3282.186, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: e7deaa74b472d878c9f9f99d5a77fe9a
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
    at Cancel.main(Cancel.java:141)
```

Comment: You probably tackle this using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835179/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-ajax-response

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'lt07', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=64.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *2.53.1* of *2016-06-30 17:37:03* which is almost 2 years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_101** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u101* , *Selenium Client v2.53.1* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v64.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.9.1**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**ChromeDriver v2.35**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v64.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.